# .exe closes immediately after launch when double clicked

Tags: python, cmd, exe, py2exe

I've created an `exe` file using `py2exe` module. The weird thing is that it works as it has to work when I run the `exe` from command line but when I double-click on this `exe`, it opens a console (as it has to do) and the console closes immediately.

I wrote a `logging` method to figure out where is the problem and surrounded the method by `try-except` which does not catch any exception.

Here is a piece of my code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        mh = moto()
        db = database() # you can find __init__ of database() below
        log('ok') # I CAN'T FIND THIS LINE IN THE LOG FILE SO THE PROBLEM IS PROBABLY INSIDE __INIT__ OD database()
    except Exception as e: 
        log(str(e))
        log(str(traceback.format_exc))

    for url in [__CATs__,__hyphens__]:
        log(' for url')
```

**init** database():

```
class database():

    def __init__(self):
            self.conn = sqlite3.connect('db.db') # Database is created
            self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
            self.create_table_moto()
            self.drop_and_create_temp_table()
            log('init_end') # I CAN FIND THIS LINE IN LOG FILE SO THE PROBLEM SHOULD BE AFTER database() initialization but i doubt that because of the log right after database()
```

So the main weird thing is that `__init__` method of database() is probably working correctly because I can see the last line `log('init_end')` in my log file. But rigth after this initialization is another log `log('ok')` which I don't see in a log file and no exception has been catched.

VERY IMPORTANT EDIT:

When you are creating an exe file using py2exe, it creates a folder `dist` in the folder where is your project stored. The exe file can be started using cmd only when I'm in this parent folder so I have to write `dist\moto.exe`. `moto.exe` or `project\dist\moto.exe` does not work.
EDIT:

Another weird thing:

I've added line: `mLib.printToFile('testovaci_txt.txt', 'nieco')` right after `log('ok')` which is not working and it creates the file `testovaci_txt.txt` in the folder where the 'exe' and other files are stored.

EDIT2: The `log` method is in my external library inside `site-packages`. To figure out where does `log('ok')` saves the file I've created 'log_2('ok')' which creates a file `logging-testing.txt` and put it right after `log('ok')` and starts the program. Then I searched for this file in Windows and it can't find it.

Do you know where could be the problem?

Comment: set your path or use full path with filenames. Double-clicking runs in `%windir%\system32` by default (probably that's not where your file resides)

Comment: @Stephan The weird is that I use this approach very often and everything works fine. I can't use full path because I'm going to send an exe to my friend. So how could I set my path? Thanks

Comment: As @Stephan says, it probably has to do with the path. It looks as if `class database` is logging in a different path than your `__main__`. You might find another log with that 'ok' in an unexpected path if no error was thrown.

Comment: As a test, you could try to run your `exe` in the command line but _from another path different from where the executable is_ and see what happens.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's the default behaviour in windows. If you want to see the output of your program before the console closes, add a raw_input() read at the end of your program, so it gets suspended with your output.

Comment: @cnluzon I tried. It makes a database and log file in the dir where I actually am but the log is exactly the same as when I run it double-click. Of course it raises an Exception than because it couldn't do something but the Exception should be catched and it obviousi isn't.

Comment: I've added an edit to this question. I've put line which has to create a file, right after not working 'log.txt' and this line works correctly.

Comment: Log `os.getcwd()`, and compare those when running from the commandprompt and when running by doubleclicking it.

Comment: Thank you guys. The mistake was obvious but I didn't noticed that. In db file, where database class is stored there were some lines in the bottom of the file which starts instantiating database class. But I don't know why it worked when I start it this way: dist\moto.exe and didn't work this way cd dist; moto.exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's by design.

If you double-click the exe it runs and than it closes.
You may to put a "raw_input()" (for Python2) or "input()" (for Python3) at the end of the file (after " log(' for url') " but with the indentation used for " for url in [__CATs__,__hyphens__]: ").

About the 'ok' in the log, is the log() function something you created? If so, do you append '\n' to every line of the log before writing the file?